# Can a un-used NONCLUSTERED INDEX still enhance query speed?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, index-tuning, sql-server-2016, nonclustered-index

This is a strange situation, but I'm hoping someone has an answer.

During some performance troubleshooting, we added a NONCLUSTERED INDEX to a table, as was requested by `sp_BlitzIndex`.  We checked its usage the next day, and it showed *0 reads* (*0 scans/seeks, 0 singleton lookups*), so we disabled it.

The very next minute, we get a complaint of the same app-slowness (performance trouble) that we were trying to check out & resolve in the first place when we added the INDEX.

Now, I know in theory, this sounds purely coincidental.  The INDEX was provably, measurably, **NOT USED**.  Disabling it *SHOULD NOT* have caused query performance degradation.  But it's almost *TOO* coincidental.

## Question

So my question, simply enough, is thus:

Is it *at all possible*, that a NONCLUSTERED INDEX, whose usage-stats (from the DMVs / `sp_BlitzIndex`) show NO usage, still have been **helping** query performance somehow on the affected table?

Comment: PS: Please spare me the proverbial "Go test it!" response; I have to wait until tomorrow to test it because the table is heavily used and the index won't be re-enabled (re-built) until the nightly maintenance window.  And the nature of the performance troubles has been sporadic & difficult to reproduce anyway; I'm not saying "No, I won't test it", I'm saying I know we have to test, and plan on it, but I'm asking for theory and/or experiential knowledge.

Comment: You might find this blog post useful; https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/11/can-indexes-query-doesnt-use-help-query/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it could, when SQL Server decides that the statistics from that index is more accurate/useful and uses that stats to do the estimates and come up with a plan.

I have come across situations when SQL Server has decided to use stats from one index and scan/seek another index.

Edit - This might not be applicable cause I just realized that you have disabled the index.  I have not tested that scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the clear, concise response!  Yeah no, it wasn't disabled immediately, it was enabled & fully "live" until I disabled it seconds before the user-complaint / performance-slowdown.  You're good :)

Comment: @NateJ That theory may be tested by `CREATE STATISTICS` instead of `CREATE INDEX`.